# Get cell content on a Gridpane

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to do a boardgame using JavaFX. The game is Carcassone.

I decided to use a GridPane to draw the board, so I can access with an x, y coordenates to each tile, and that makes sense with the logical board which is a HashMap, so for each x, y position I add the tile in the logical board and it also gets added to the draw board (the gridpane).

But, for each tile added in the GridPane, I want to add "void tiles" in the adjacent tiles which are empty. Let's suppose green tiles are the tiles played, blue are the adjacent and white is the rest of the gridpane, which it's void (null vallue):

[image]
So new tiles (green) can only be added to blue positions, and for each green tile added if the adjacent ones are empty they get "blue".

So the problem is, how to know if an adjacent tile is empty. I've found this function:

```
private boolean tileEmpty(int row, int column, GridPane gridPane) {
    Node result = null;
    ObservableList<Node> childrens = gridPane.getChildren();

    for (Node node : childrens) {
        if(GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row && GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == column) {
            result = node;
            break;
        }
    }
    return (result == null);
}
```

But it gives me a NullPointerException as I create the gridpane at this way:

```
private void crearTauler() {
    GridPane _taulerVisual = new GridPane();
    _taulerVisual.setPrefSize(800,600);
    _taulerVisual.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    _taulerVisual.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    _taulerVisual.setHgap(4);
    _taulerVisual.setVgap(3);
}
```

And this is the tile adder function, which is in the same class as the other functions:

```
public class myTile extends Imageview {...}
```

.

```
public void addVisualTile(myTile r, int x, int y) {
    myVisualTile rV = new myVisualTile(r);
    myVisualTile add = new myVisualTile();
    _taulerVisual.add(rV, x, y);

    // And this is the code I'd to make work:
    if (tileEmpty(x-1, y, _taulerVisual)) {
        _taulerVisual.add(add, x-1, y);
    }
    else if (tileEmpty(x+1, y, _taulerVisual)) {
        _taulerVisual.add(add, x+1, y);
    }
    else if (tileEmpty(x, y-1, _taulerVisual)) {
        _taulerVisual.add(add, x, y-1);
    }
    else if (tileEmpty(x, y+1, _taulerVisual)) {
        _taulerVisual.add(add, x, y+1);
    }
}
```

So the thing is that I can't iterate in the gridpane as all childs except some are empty. Any idea to solve that problem?

Comment: You should create a model class representing the board (something more complicated than a `HashMap`). It will make it easier to query for the information you want since it will be implemented by you.

Comment: @Slaw I've seen you answered both questions I made, thanks m8! Probably I will have to make a class board, with a boolean atribbute for each position and something like that. But in our APP we have a logical board, which is a HashMap but it saves more information. And we want to make that board visible. Do ou think that adding a gridpane attribute to that board is a good solution?

Comment: The model should be completely ignorant of the view.